# Removing non-repository files with git?

Tags: git

I'm writing Autotools code and in the process of development, tons of files are generated.

Is there anyway to tell git to remove all files from a directory that are not part of the repository?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You can use [git-clean](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html). This command will remove untracked files/directories. By default, it will only print what it would have removed, without actually removing them.

Given the `-f` flag to remove the files, and the `-d` flag to remove empty directories as well :

```
git clean -df
```

Also removing ignored files :

```
git clean -dfx
```

Comment: Throw in a `-x` and it's all as good as a freshly cloned repo.

Comment: I thought he meant remove files from git, not the actual filesystem, whoops!

Comment: The command `git clean` on its own will actually remove all untracked files - except when  the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is set to true. If its set to false, then -ff is needed for cleaning diretories

Comment: Recent versions of git will error without any parameters; requireForce defaults to true, so to do a dryrun you need -n

Comment: following up on  @Dustin :  `git clean -ix` will show you what it will clean and give you a menu of options. My favorite.

Comment: `git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xfd` does the same thing recursively to submodules per https://gist.github.com/nicktoumpelis/11214362

Comment: Cool! I'll remember `git clean -dfx` as [Das EFX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PU22-fsGA0)